# Does Ember-table support for ember 2.3.0?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-table

Ember-table by Addepar Inc., is really cool but it is not supported in Ember 2.3.0. Is there any way to make it work in Ember 2.3.0 app? I tried Ember-cli-ember-table also. But it also didn't work for me. If you guys know the proper installation procedure and usage, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

As long as I understand they have been working on it, but facing some performance issues related to glimmer (no ember-views support anymore, requires migration).
https://github.com/Addepar/ember-table/issues/389